# How to loop through two list of lists at once and replace values from one list with the other list?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, nested-loops

I have two lists of lists (a and b)

They both have only 2 indexes per row.

`a` (50,000 rows) looks like this:

```
|name|age|
|----|---|
|Dany|021|
|Alex|035|
```

As a list of lists, looks like this:

```
[['Dany', '021'],['Alex','035'], etc...]
```

`b` (2000 rows) looks like this:

```
|name|age|
|----|---|
|Paul|   |
|Leon|   |
```

As a list of lists, looks like this:

```
[['Paul', ''],['Leon',''], etc...]
```

Question: I want to iterate through `a` and `b` at the same time - for each iteration of `a`, if `a[0]` is in `b[0]`, I want to add the corresponding `a[1]` into `b[1]`.

In lay terms, I want to add ages to my `b` list by going through my `a` list, checking if the name is in the `a` list and if it is, taking that corresponding age and adding it in the `b` list for that corresponding name.

I have tried a nested loop (iterating through b and for each iteration, iterating through `a` to check if any iteration of `a` at `a[0]` exists in that iteration of `b` at `b[0]`) but just keep getting lost after that.

```
for row in b[1:]: # Excluding the headers
    b_name = row[0]
    b_age = row[1]
    for row in a[1:]:
        if b_name in row[0]:
            b_age = row[1]
        else:
            b_age = ''
```

The issue is that I end up getting just one value for `b_age`, but there should be 2000 unique `b_age` values?

Comment: These should be dictionaries, not lists of lists. Or you should use `pandas`.

Comment: Setting `b_age` to a value does not affect the list column that it came from.

Comment: You're not adding anything, you're just replacing the variable. Do you mean you want to add them as numbers, concatenate strings, or make a list of all the values?

Comment: @Barmar how should I use pandas in this case?

Comment: It has methods for joining the two tables based on common keys, and `groupby` to combine all the rows with the same key.

Comment: @Barmar I want to replace the ' ' empty string with a string from the other list of lists

Comment: IMO, pandas is _massive_ overkill for a project this small and with such straightforward requirements.

Comment: @KirkStrauser But he might have more things he wants to do with these tables, so pandas may be useful in general.

Comment: I’d cross that bridge when it comes up. It feels like a premature optimization to bring in a dependency like that before you run out of efficient standard library options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the names in `a` are unique, you could create a dict from `a` to avoid looping through it over and over as you replace the empty string values in `b`. For example (added a couple items to your examples to illustrate what would happen if a name in `b` does not exist in `a`):

```
a = [['Dany', '021'], ['Alex','035'], ['Joe', '054']]
b = [['Alex',''], ['Dany', ''], ['Jane', '']]

d = {k: v for k, v in a}
b = [[k, d[k]] if k in d else [k, v] for k, v in b]
print(b)
# [['Alex', '035'], ['Dany', '021'], ['Jane', '']]
```

If the list you are actually working with is just a simple list of pairs as in the example, then you could replace the dict comprehension above with `dict(a)`.

Also, in case it is not clear, the various `k, v` references are for convenience in unpacking the nested pairs, but you could just use a single variable and access using index values like:

```
{x[0]: x[1] for x in a}
```

Comment: Thanks @benvc so if it's not a simple list of pairs how would I go about it?

Comment: @luca-martial - depending on how complex your nested lists are you might be able to use modified version of the dict comprehension in this answer. If the nested lists are quite complex, then it would be helpful if you posted an example of what they look like so we can better help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make a dict of the ages so that you can do a series of fast O(1) lookups for each row in `b`. I'd start with something like:

```
# Make a dictionary of names to their ages
age = dict(a)

for row in b:
    try:
        # Set the age of this row to the age of row[0]
        row[1] = age[row[0]]
    except KeyError:
        # End up here if row[0] is not in the "ages" dict
        pass
```

Comment: On which part? It runs as expected here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make `a` into a dictionary by doing `a_dict = dict(a)` which will result in something like this:

```
{'Dany': '021', 'Alex': '035', etc...}
```

Then you can do something simple like this:

```
for person in b:
    if person[0] in a_dict:
        person[1] = a_dict[person[0]]
```

That should give you something like this in `b`:

```
[['Paul', ''], ['Leon', ''], ['Alex', '035'], etc...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update values in `b`, you need to loop over b's *row index*.  Looping over the *values* won't work, as they don't keep their linkage back to the source row/column in `b`.

Also, presumably you want to assign a blank age as the second column in `b` only if *none* of the names in `a` match, not just if the *current* name doesn't match.

Try this instead:

```
for b_row_index in range(1, len(b)): # Excluding the headers
    b_name = b[b_row_index][0]
    for a_row in a[1:]:
        if b_name in a_row[0]:
            b[b_row_index][1] = a_row[1]
            break
    else:
        b[b_row_index][1] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

with lists you can:

```
a = [['Dany', '021'],['Alex','035'], ['Paul', '060'],['Leon','070']]
b = [['Paul', ''],['Leon','']]

for i, b_item in enumerate(b):
    for a_item in a:
        if b_item[0]==a_item[0]:
            b[i] = a_item
            break

print(b)
```

**output**:

```
[['Paul', '060'], ['Leon', '070']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as many others mentioned; using dictionaries here, would make life much easier, you can convert to dictionaries, process your data and append ages then convert back to lists if that is what you need. This code does exactly that:

```py
a = [['Dany', '021'], ['Alex','035'], ['Joe', '054']]
b = [['Alex',''], ['Dany', ''], ['Jane', '']]

print(a)
print(b)
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

# convert to dict for simplicity
a_dictionary  = dict(zip([e[0] for e in a], [e[1] for e in a]))
b_dictionary  = dict(zip([e[0] for e in b], [e[1] for e in b]))
a_intersect_b = list(set(a_dictionary.keys()) & set(b_dictionary.keys()))

print(a_dictionary)
print(b_dictionary)
print(a_intersect_b)
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

# copy ages to b
for k in a_intersect_b:
    b_dictionary[k] = a_dictionary[k]

print(a_dictionary)
print(b_dictionary)
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')

# go back to lists
a = [[name, age] for name, age in zip(a_dictionary.keys(), a_dictionary.values())]
b = [[name, age] for name, age in zip(b_dictionary.keys(), b_dictionary.values())]

print(a)
print(b)
print('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
```

**Output:**

```
[['Dany', '021'], ['Alex', '035'], ['Joe', '054']]
[['Alex', ''], ['Dany', ''], ['Jane', '']]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
{'Dany': '021', 'Alex': '035', 'Joe': '054'}
{'Alex': '', 'Dany': '', 'Jane': ''}
['Alex', 'Dany']
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
{'Dany': '021', 'Alex': '035', 'Joe': '054'}
{'Alex': '035', 'Dany': '021', 'Jane': ''}
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[['Dany', '021'], ['Alex', '035'], ['Joe', '054']]
[['Alex', '035'], ['Dany', '021'], ['Jane', '']]
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```